# Deselect or save current cell in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically what I'm struggling with is I'm trying to create a timesheet for staff members at work, where at the end of the shift they go in and enter their start time end time etc and then they click add shift and it exports the data to another sheet (I have the code for this all done).

my issue is that unless I go and deselect the final cell before clicking add shift, the cell is not saved and then not exported to the other sheet.

I've dropped the link below so you can go in and have a look and see what I mean, any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19W6XLlgSE4Kk2B-gIBPljojhWgz_a1qE0d4F9IiUqcM/edit?usp=sharing

```
function submitData() {
   
  var myGooglSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var shUserForm= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("TimeSheet Entry"); 
  var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("TimeSheet"); 

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 
 if (true==true) {
  
    var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1; //identify the next blank row
 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A2").getValue()); // Name
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B2").getValue()); // Start
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C2").getValue()); // FInish
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 4).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D2").getValue()); // Break start
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E2").getValue()); // Break end
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F2").getValue());// Del
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 7).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G2").getValue());// Auth
   
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd h:mm');
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 9).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dddd');
    ui.alert("Your shift has been added, thanks "+shUserForm.getRange("A2").getValue());
  
 
    shUserForm.getRange("A2").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("B2").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C2").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("D2").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("E2").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("F2").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("G2").clear();     
 }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't a Google Form work fine for this?

Comment: There is a lot more formatting that needs to be done after the data has been put in so a google form wouldn't suit this

Comment: `my issue is that unless I go and deselect the final cell before clicking add shift, the cell is not saved and then not exported to the other sheet.` can you provide more details here? Also your code needs a lot of improvements. E.g. `true==true` does not make sense because it will always be true. So the `if` is useless. Also there is `getValues` and `setValues` you can use instead to get and set **multiplle** values at once. The same for all the `clear` lines you have. You can replace them with `shUserForm.getRange("A2:G2").clear();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

I think your goal is to submit the new records only when the checkbox is checked:

```
shUserForm.getRange("B3").getValue()==true
```

Also I removed some of your code. E.g.:

- `true==true` is always true and therefore is not needed.
- You can get and set values in an array instead of calling `getValue` and `setValue` multiple times which is not efficient.

### Solution:

```
function submitData() {
   
  const myGooglSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  const shUserForm= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("TimeSheet Entry"); 
  const datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("TimeSheet"); 
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  if (shUserForm.getRange("B3").getValue()==true) {      
    const blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1; //identify the next blank row
    const values = shUserForm.getRange("A2:G2").getValues();
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,1,1,values[0].length).setValues(values);
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd h:mm');
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 9).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dddd');
    ui.alert("Your shift has been added, thanks "+shUserForm.getRange("A2").getValue());
    shUserForm.getRange("A2:G2").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("B3").setValue(false);        
 }
}
```

To store a new record you must check the box in cell `B3`. After the record is archived, the script will untick the box for you.